# Mac Mini + Thunderbolt Display+ Additional Display?

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt-display

I just purchased a 2012 Mac Mini to use with my Apple Thunderbolt Display.

The mini also included an HDMI to DVI converter.  I have a DVI-connected ViewSonic montior that I'd like to use as a secondary display.  Is it possible to use the HDMI-out port as a secondary monitor output?

Like so: (excuse the horrible art)

```
     Thunderbolt Port          HDMI Port
    /*****************|------|**********\_________
   |                  | Mac  |          |         |
---------------       | Mini |          | Other   |
| Thunderbolt |       |------|          | Monitor |
|   Display   |                         |_________|
|_____________|
```

Comment: if you have all the parts, why not just try and see if it works?..

Comment: My DVI Cable vanished, so I didn't want to buy one if it wasn't going to do me any good. It's funny how I can spend $1000 on a monitor and another $1000+ on the Mini... but that last $5 is just too much. ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Accepting as the correct answer, or I'll forget to come back.  Haven't tried it yet though :)